# Apostrophe CMS, how to style rich text in a piece

Tags: css, apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I have follow your guide about people piece: http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces.html

Here is the biography definition:

```
{
    name: 'body',
    label: 'Biography',
    type: 'area',
    options: {
        widgets: {
            'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                controls: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink']
            },
            'apostrophe-images': { }
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore I thought I could style biography. However, neither in the modal dialog, nor in the people-page I see the toolbar to style the text.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That is not our guide. We have nothing to do with ApostropheCMS. If you were looking for their discussion forum, that would be http://forum.apostrophecms.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide has a typo .. the `controls` property should be `toolbar`

```
{
    name: 'body',
    label: 'Biography',
    type: 'area',
    options: {
        widgets: {
            'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                toolbar: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink']
            },
            'apostrophe-images': { }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll fix the docs, thanks!